# Xamarin Forms Mobile App - Is it possible to track position of pen stylus?

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, samsung-mobile, skiasharp

I am writing an Android drawing mobile app using Xamarin Forms and SkiaSharp. The mobile tablet that I am using has a pen stylus (Samsung Galaxy Tab). When I hover the stylus over the screen, the tablet is able to recognize where the position of the nib and displays a small circle where it will land.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to access the hover position information of the stylus please?

Thanks

Comment: Probably make a [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

Comment: At the heart of all gestures is a special class called Android.Gestures.GestureDetector, you may consider implementing it.   And the GetpointId method and the PointId property may  be used to get the position of the stylus in the view.

Comment: I downloaded a demo project that uses the GestureDetector and unfortunately it does not seem to trigger with hover over with the stylus. I think the MotionEvent may hold some clues as that seems to suggest it captures pens and mice. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent

Comment: Yes,  you may try getting the pointerIndex in the onTouchEvent method with the MotionEvent parameter.

Comment: I have finally cracked it and will post a more detailed answer shortly. I used a TouchEffect that utilises the GenericMotion event handler (Android.Views.View). From there it is able to capture hover over events without user requiring to touch the screen.